# Ubuntu + optane?

Tags: intel

I want to change to ubuntu, but mi pc (Acer Aspire 5 A515-51-83XM) works with optane (Intel Core i7 8550U, 4GB DDR4 + 16 GB Intel Optane). Actually runninf windows 10.

I don't know if optane works well with ubuntu, I read that it can't use it as a system accelerator.

I'd like to know if this is true or if I can change to ubuntu. If so, which version?

ps: never had an linux based OS before so I dont undestand so much about it.

Comment: Boot from a LiveCD or LiveUSB Stick, and you can try Ubuntu without installing.